# css media queriesto hide or show content

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Ok so I cant see whats up with this, I have two `divs`

**html**

```
<div id="desktop-content">
desktop
</div>

<div id="mobile-content">
mobile
</div>
```

One should print mobile if on mobile screen and hide the desktop and the other show on desktop but hide on mobile.

**Here is my queries**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 200px) {
    #mobile-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 201px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #mobile-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 200px) {
    #desktop-content { display: none; }  /* hide it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 201px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #desktop-content { display: block; }   /* show it elsewhere */
}
```

seems simple enough, except desktop is printing when mobile should, and on desktop its all printing.

Im new to media queries, If someone could point out the error of my ways i would appreciate it.

Comment: your code works. See the fiddle. 

https://jsfiddle.net/3q0mukLy/

Comment: Hmm, i thought it should. must be a problem else where. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was simple mistake I was viewing on a widescreen monitor outside the parameters of the css. simple fix.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #mobile-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px)  {
    #mobile-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #desktop-content { display: none; }  /* hide iton small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #desktop-content { display: block; }   /* show it elsewhere */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, say by default you want the mobile to show. Causes you to get the following:

```
#mobile-content {
    display: block;
}

#desktop-content {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #mobile-content {
        display: none;
    }

    #desktop-content {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This should cause the mobile content to be default visible and the desktop content to be default on invisible. When a screen has 768px or more, it will switch and will hide the mobile content and show the desktop content. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First done use same css multiple time

Change your code like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #mobile-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
    #desktop-content { display: none; }  /* hide it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 789px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #mobile-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
    #desktop-content { display: block; }   /* show it elsewhere */
}
```

> we consider mobile and tablet screen starts from 768px

Here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/3r1qe2Lc/3/

> check resizing the fiddle

Comment: showing mobile and desctop, same problem im getting

Comment: please create a fiddle with problem